# Error while try to test app on physical device

Tags: xamarin.ios

When I run the App in a simulator it works perfect, but when I try to deploy the App on my physical device it shows the following error:

> (Can't resolve the reference
>   'System.Void MaterialComponents.Card::SetShadowElevation(System.Double,UIKit.UIControlState)',
>   referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Material.MaterialFrameRenderer::SetupLayer()' in
>   'MaterialComponents, Version=1.0.6836.23950, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (MT2101) (Yucaz.Mobile.iOS))

Comment: Did you use some nuget package?